# Apply effect over image with CSS

Tags: html, css, effect

I have a background image with many details, and I need to apply some kind of css/html filter to have this effect:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/ihYRYiJ.png]

(left side with a layer effect over it, right side without)
(example was applied with photoshop).

Already tried to overlay an image with opacity, but can't reproduce the same thing.

Comment: Not really sure what you would like to do. Do you want to take the color from the background image?

Comment: I have a div with a background image. Must apply an overlayer div to have a similar effect like the left side of the example image. (The right side of the image is what I have so far without any effect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That filter can be reproduced by using a multiply blend mode. To get the effect, use `mix-blend-mode: multiply` on an overlay element, like this:

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#div1 {
  background-color: gray;
  border: solid black 3px;
}

#div2 {
  background-color: teal;
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<!-- Underlying div -->
<div id="div1">
</div>

<!-- Overlay div -->
<div id="div2">
</div>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/sn82mb9v/

Comment: Thanks so much!! Fixed